# How to proxy a http request through Charles

Tags: proxy, charles-proxy

I have a mac mini that is sharing it's wifi connection. It's broadcasting the wifi network `foobar`. I connect to the network from Mac Pro, if I visit the following address `http://192.168.22.93:8888/` from my Mac Pro my requests are proxied through Charles. This makes sense bc that is the IP of the computer running Charles, and Charles is running on port 8888. So far so good.

The problem is I want to proxy a request to yahoo though Charles i.e.
`http://192.168.22.93:8888/?url=http://yahoo.com`
To which Charles returns:

```
Charles Error Report

Failure

Malformed request URL "/?url=http://yahoo.com". Consider enabling Transparent proxying.

The actual exception reported was:

com.xk72.proxy.ProxyException: Malformed request URL "/?url=http://yahoo.com". Consider enabling Transparent proxying.
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same problem. Can you share the solution if you found it?